# I want to get values from specific items in a text file to build a new text file using the values from the first using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have 1100+ text files with values like 'BlinkTextStyle="1"' and 'ForgroundColor="150,150,150"'. The old files only have 200 of these values, the new files that I will be creating will have over 100 new values besides the current 200. Some of the new values will be based on the one of the old values. The structure of the files are the feature="value"  feature="value". I have a script that goes out and locates all the users files of this type, I just need a way to harvest the values from the old file, backup the old file, delete the old file, create the new file with the harvested and modified values with the same name as the original. The old and new files will have a cfg file extension. The files are located on the users computer but are accessible from the server witch this script is run on. Below is a sample of the file contents. Thank you in advance for any help or direction. This should all be done using PowerShell.

```
Version 60 (60.0.6053.0)
ODTmode="false"
FontName="Lucida Sans Typewriter"
RegularTextSize="14"
RegularTextStyle="1"
BrightTextStyle="1"
BlinkTextStyle="1"
ReverseTextStyle="1"
StatusLineTextStyle="1"
UnderLineTextStyle="1"
BackgroundColor="204,51,255"
RegularTextColor="0,51,0"
BlinkTextColor="0,0,51"
ReverseTextColor="102,0,51"
BrightTextColor="51,0,51"
ReverseBlinkTextColor="51,51,51"
```

New Code

```
    # Original Config Files
    $Files = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp -Include *.cfg -Recurse).FullName
    # Example of this     SmithBob_BSComputer_File1.cfg
    
    
    # Keys derived from a blank new cfg file
    $Keys = Get-content "C:\temp\keys.txt"
    # Examples of keys
        # FontName
        # Blink
        # ReverseBlink
        # RegularSizedText
    
    foreach ($File in $Files)
        {
        # Gathering Filename, Computername and Username
        $Data = $File.split("_")
        $NewFileName = $Data[2]
        $VDI = $Data[1]
        $Username = $Data[0]
        
        # Hashing the file
        $hashtable = @{}
        $hash = Get-Content $File
    
        foreach($Line in $hash)
            {
            $Linesplit=$Line.split("=")
            $Line1=$Linesplit[0]
            $line2=$Linesplit[1]
            $hashtable.add($Line1,$Line2)
            }#foreach
    
        
        # get value for each key
        Foreach ($Key in $Keys)
            {
            # Adding Version information
            $Complete = "Version 60 (60.0.680.0)"
            # Get the value of each key
                # Special Keys
                If (($Key -eq "BlinkTextBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "ReverseTextBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "ReverseBlinkTextBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "ReverseBrightTextBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "BlinkBrightTextBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "BlinkReverseBrightTextBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "StatusLineBackgroundColor") -or ($Key -eq "UnderLineTextBackgroundColor"))
                    {
                    #make value same as "BackgroundColor"
                    Write-host "
                    $Key being processed
                    " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                    $Complete += $Key,$hastable.BackgroundColor
                    } # End If
                    ElseIf ($Key -eq "BrightTextBackgroundColor")
                        {
                        # Value not found in original but must be in new and not another already defined value
                        Write-host "
                        $Key being processed
                        " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                        $Complete += $Key,"102,255,204"
                        } # End Elsif
                        Elseif (($Key -eq "StatusLineTextColor") -or ($Key -eq "UnderLineTextColor") -or ($Key -eq "InfoLineTextColor")) 
                            {
                            # Value not found in original but must be in new and not another already defined value
                            Write-host "
                            $Key being processed
                            " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                            $Complete += $Key,"java.awt.SystemColor[i=18]"
                            } # End Elsif
                            ElseIf ($Key -eq "InfoLineBackgroundColor")
                                {
                                # Value not found in original but must be in new and not another already defined value
                                Write-host "
                                $Key being processed
                                " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                                $Complete += $key,"238,238,238"
                                } # End Elsif
                                ElseIf ($Key -eq "Numpad_Enter")
                                    {
                                    # Value not found in original but must be in new and not another already defined value
                                    Write-host "
                                    $Key being processed
                                    " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                                    $Complete += $key,"<RETURN>"
                                    } # End Elsif
                                    Elseif (($key -eq "StatusLineTextStyle") -or ($Key -eq "UnderlinTextStyle"))
                                        {
                                        # Value not found in original but must be in new and not another already defined value
                                        Write-host "
                                        $Key being processed
                                        " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                                        $Complete += $Key,"0"
                                        } # End Elseif
                                        Else
                                            {
                                            # Add that Key and value to variable $complete
                                            Write-host "
                                            $Key being processed
                                            " -ForegroundColor Cyan
                                            $Complete += $Key,$hastable.$key
                                            } # End Else
            } # End Foreach
    
    
        # Backup old file
        $NewFilePath = "\\"+$VDI+"\D$\Unisys\Web Enabler\"+$NewFileName
        $BackupFolder = "\\"+$VDI+"\D$\Unisys\Web Enabler\"+"Backup"
        If (Test-Path $BackupFolder)
            {
            Write-Host "
            Backup folder was located! 
    
            Moving file $NewFileName to Backup folder for safe keeping.
            " -ForegroundColor Cyan
    
            Move-Item $NewFilePath -Destination $BackupFolder
            } # End If
            Else
                {
                Write-Host "
                Backup folder was not located!
    
                Creating Backup folder
                 
                Moving file $NewFileName to Backup folder for safe keeping.
                " -ForegroundColor Cyan
    
                New-Item $BackupFolder -ItemType Directory
                 Move-Item $NewFilePath -Destination $BackupFolder
                 } # End Else
    
        # Write data to new CFG file
    
        Write-Host "
        Creating new $NewFileName file for $Username
        " -ForegroundColor Green
           
        New-Item $NewFilePath -ItemType File -Value $complete
    
        # Nullifiying Variables
        $Complete = $null
        $Hashtable = $null
        
    
    
        } # End Foreach
```

Comment: Please show the code of your attempt to perform the task.

Comment: I am not even sure where to start on this. My first thought was to harvest all of the settings into a spreadsheet, add the new settings in bulk to the spreadsheet then build the new files from the spreadsheet. I am still not sure how to get that done.

Comment: If all feature names are unique in a single file, then I would use a hash table. You can look at the `-split` and `-match` operators or `select-string` to grab the relevant text from each line. An example would be `$hash = @{}; $key,$value = 'ODTmode="false"' -split '='; $hash[$key] = $value`

Comment: OK, I am getting a little closer however I cannot get my information to populate the new file. I was able to load the old file with it's values into a hashtable. I have a foreach loop where I am trying to add each key pair to a variable "$Complete += $key,$hastable.$Key" that is not working. The file gets created but it is empty. Added new code to original question (See above)

Comment: `$Complete` is not an array so `+=` doesn't do what you expect it to do. To make it an array, create it with syntax `$Complete = ,"Version 60 (60.0.680.0)"`. If you want the format of `key=value`, you will need to construct a string that does that --> `"{0}={1}" -f $key,$hashtable.$key`.